# Android tab titles lowercase

Tags: android, tabs, lowercase

maybe not a big deal, but I can't get this to work. I have a tab navigation, and I am taking the tab titles from strings.xml as an array:

```
 String[] tbTitles= resources.getStringArray(R.array.tabname);

    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(tbTitles[i])
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

The tabnames are defined as lowercase (or better to say Capitalized - **Example**). It is working fine, but the issue is on older API's, where every tab title is uppercase.

I went through some solutions on this forum, but didn't find any solution.

I tried to put this in my for loop:

```
 tbTitles[i] = tbTitles[i].toLowerCase();
```

I also tried to put this to my tablayout style in styles.xml:

```
 <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
```

The text is always Uppercase on older androids. Of course it is working for the newer API's.

All I want is to Capitalize the titles also for older API's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no solution worked for me, finally I solved it like this:

In my styles.xml to `<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">`

i just put

```
 <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/My.TabText.Style</item>
```

and then below:

```
 <style name="My.TabText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

This is the only solution that works for me!

So the point was to add `android:actionBarTabTextStyle`  and not `tabTextAppearance`

Answer (score 4):

If you add the following line to your TabLayout it should work:

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
```

Comment: well, I have no tablayout in xml file, I have only <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> and when I put it there it says TextAppearance not found. Also it is not working when I use it in my styles.xml in Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The default theme for tab views in Android 4.0 (the Holo theme) has `android:textAllCaps set to true.` So you cannot go without rewriting tablayout style. If you don't have it, just add it as it's meant to be used with viewpager

```
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
  <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

And implement it using

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
    .../>
```

Comment: It says tabTextAppearance is not known. Finally I solved it with   <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/My.TabText.Style</item>